# Unable to reference custom class in ASP.NET Web site project

Tags: asp.net

I have a class located in the APP_CODE folder. It's not recognized by Visual Studio as a type.

Here is a schematic:

```
Solution
->Web site project
-->App_Code folder
--->myBasePage.cs
```

myBasePage is not being I guess "compiled" into to a class/type.

Where do I change the build action?

Comment: Do you have the text of the error message?

Comment: Never mind, I was mis-spelling my class name, LOL...

Comment: Show please some code (beginning) of this class and place where you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to add the using directive of the file's namespace where you want to reference your class. Post the code and I can tell you exactly what to add if you like.

More than likely your namespace is MyBasePage
so in your code behind file that you are trying to reference your app_code class you would need to have, 
using myBasePage;